# Flutter - Close barcode scanner after scan in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I am using this package [package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_barcode_scanner/install) for scanning barcode. It works fine but after successfully scan I want to close the camera. I searched for the solution but no solution worked in my case. Here is my code.

```
    try {
      FlutterBarcodeScanner.getBarcodeStreamReceiver(
              '#ff6666', 'Cancel', true, ScanMode.BARCODE)!
          .listen((data) {
        print(data);
       
      });
    } on PlatformException {
      // barcodeScanRes = 'Failed to get platform version.';
    }
  }
```

Comment: Did you got the solution? In case of continous scanning, how to stop after a successful scan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can close scan page by adding this line to your code

```
if (barcodeScanRes != null){
   print(barcodeScanRes);
   // this will send your scan result to previous page
   // or you can navigate to other page after scan success
   Navigator.pop(context, barcodeScanRes); 
}
```

```
String barcodeScanRes; // put this variable in statefull widget
Future<void> scanQR() async {
  try {
    barcodeScanRes = await FlutterBarcodeScanner.scanBarcode(
        '#ff6666', 'Cancel', true, ScanMode.QR);
    // add this line to close scanner or naivigate to other page
    if (barcodeScanRes != null){
       print(barcodeScanRes);
       Navigator.pop(context, barcodeScanRes);
    }
  } on PlatformException {
    barcodeScanRes = 'Failed to get platform version.';
  }

  if (!mounted) return;
  setState(() {
    _scanBarcode = barcodeScanRes;
  });
}
```

or if you want to pause the camera after scan, you can use this package https://pub.dev/packages/qr_code_scanner

Comment: This is single scan. Question is for "getBarcodeStreamReceiver". I am also searching for an answer.